# Compatibility Mode in IE(Internet Explorer) 11. Windows 7.

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ie8-compatibility-mode

Need to work on an older website that supports IE 8 and IE 9 but I am using a tool that only captures websites running on IE 11. So I have IE 11 but if i turn on compatibility mode, the capturing tool does not recognize the website therefore cannot capture website controls.

I need help with anything that can help render the website in IE 11 without changing the browser back to IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft offers virtual machine downloads on their website here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

There's IE8 up to IE11, these virtual machines are limited to 90 days (but you can start fresh afterwards). This unfortunately means there's no seamless integration with your current OS and developer tools.

Comment: Thanks but still not able to capture controls. The tools needs to capture IE 11 websites only.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with the tool then? What tool is it (if you are able to name it, or maybe not if it's internal/unreleased)?

Comment: Its an internal tool. Not able to name it, basically captures website controls but only captures IE 10 and 11 compatible websites.